Missing icons in Dock after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
I have several program pinned to my Dock: some work perfectly, others behave strangely after updating. The .desktop files are configured properly.
I don't know exactly how to put it in words, I'll try my best with an example.
For instance, Discord works just fine: I press the icon, the "red dot" appears close to the icon, and Discord opens.
However, when I press the IntelliJ icon, the instance shows up as a different program with a cog icon:

A similar thing happens with Skype, which I don't even have pinned on my Dock.
How do I fix this?

@vanadium it worked with intellij, but not with skype; Thanks!

Try this:

Open (=run) the application that behaves this way. Wait for its window to appear.

Press Alt+F2 and run lg. On the window displayed click on Windows and find your application. Note the string displayed after wmclass: for this application.

Find¹ the .desktop file of your application and copy the file into your ./.local/share/applications/ directory.

Edit the newly created file and add a line to the end of the [Desktop Entry] section like this:
StartupWMClass=string



where string is the string you obtained in step 2.

¹ Note: In step 3, to find the .desktop file of your application search for:
$ sudo find / -iname desktopfile

where desktopfile is the string you see after app: for this application in step 2.

This is the same as described by @vanadium, and it worked, so thank you!

I had similar "problems" after update to 24.04 and I wanted to give more detailed and step by step explanation.

Thanks for the detailed explanation - for some reason, the value StartupWMClass is for e.g. Okular already set to the correct value, but the icon is still not showing up. Any idea why that might be? Is the icon itself now stored somewhere else?

@DanDoe  Please, check to see if there are more than one desktop files with the same same, one local and one global for example. The local one will have precedence over the global one. Find the one which is active (that is used by your system). Experiment with various icon values to make sure that this is the correct file; you may need to use full path names for icon files. Post a new question describing the problem and paste the contents of your .desktop file into your question.

I can only confirm @FedKad 's suggestion regarding multiple desktop files. This is the case e.g. for PDF Studio Viewer which has a .desktop file in a subdirectory of the installation path (opt/pdfstudioviewer2024 by default on Ubuntu) and one in usr/share/applications.

I get the solution from here written in more detail, new and experienced both can easily catch it: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-app-icon-missing/
